# iOS: UIDocumentMenuViewController wrong width when opened from modal view on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller

I want to show `UIDocumentMenuViewController` from the modal view (modal presentation style set to FormSheet), but the menu shown fits not the width of the view (it is too big like the whole screen width). Is this the bug or can I do something to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?  I'm encountering the exact same problem.

Comment: @JohnHaager unfortunately not.